# Create nested Component Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-cli

want to create nested component in angular 6 . Folder structure is src->app->content->1.home,2.product
want create component in product. 
 i did this am on already in folder product  c:/users/admin/project/test/src/app/content/product> ng g component advisory on cmd

Getting Error as : Unexpected token / in JSON at position 1122

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Source copied from the [official angular-cli doc](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#generating-components-directives-pipes-and-services)

```
ng generate component my-new-component
ng g component my-new-component  // using the alias

// components support relative path generation
// if in the directory src/app/feature/ and you run
ng g component new-cmp
// your component will be generated in src/app/feature/new-cmp
// but if you were to run
ng g component ./newer-cmp
// your component will be generated in src/app/newer-cmp
// if in the directory src/app you can also run

    ng g component feature/new-cmp

// and your component will be generated in src/app/feature/new-cmp
```

Answer (score 5):

Go to the root directory where angular-cli is there

and give the command as follows

```
c :/users/admin/project/test/src/app/content > ng g c product/advisory
```

Answer (score 2):

```
C:\depot\sandbox>ng g c outside
CREATE src/app/outside/outside.component.html (22 bytes)
CREATE src/app/outside/outside.component.spec.ts (635 bytes)
CREATE src/app/outside/outside.component.ts (274 bytes)
CREATE src/app/outside/outside.component.scss (0 bytes)
UPDATE src/app/app.module.ts (546 bytes)

C:\depot\sandbox>ng g c outside/inside
CREATE src/app/outside/inside/inside.component.html (21 bytes)
CREATE src/app/outside/inside/inside.component.spec.ts (628 bytes)
CREATE src/app/outside/inside/inside.component.ts (270 bytes)
CREATE src/app/outside/inside/inside.component.scss (0 bytes)
UPDATE src/app/app.module.ts (636 bytes)

C:\depot\sandbox>ng g c outside/inside-too
CREATE src/app/outside/inside-too/inside-too.component.html (25 bytes)
CREATE src/app/outside/inside-too/inside-too.component.spec.ts (650 bytes)
CREATE src/app/outside/inside-too/inside-too.component.ts (285 bytes)
CREATE src/app/outside/inside-too/inside-too.component.scss (0 bytes)
UPDATE src/app/app.module.ts (740 bytes)
```

Example [taken from angular bug tracker on github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3570#issuecomment-272670954).